# Discord.py switching from client to bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm fairly new at making a discord bot. I have created a method to get a list of all the members in the server the bot is connected to. This method works fine. However, I am also trying to get the bot to accept commands. I am having a lot of trouble with this and I keep seeing that I should use commands.Bot for this instead of Client. I can't figure out how to make my original method work with commands.Bot though. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import os

import discord
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from discord.ext import commands




intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
outP = open("giveawayList.txt", "w")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message == "!test":
        await message.channel.send("you failed the test")
        
        
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild: \n' 
        f'{guild.name} (id: {guild.id})'
    )


    count = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
            if 'Bots' not in str(member.roles):
                
                print(member.name, ' ')
                outP.write(member.name)
                outP.write("\n")
                count += 1
    print('Number of members: ' + str(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is good to use `commands.bot` instead of `Client` because it is an extended version, as it inherits all the functionalities from `Client`.

I see you have tried to migrate from the use of `Client` to using `commands.bot`, but have a few things in mind:

You do not want to use both at the same time, so this is wrong:

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

You should keep only the bot one.

Apart from that, you gotta replace the `client` from the decorators and the calls inside the function. Your corrected code should look something like this:

```py
import os

import discord
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from discord.ext import commands
    
intents = discord.Intents.all()
outP = open("giveawayList.txt", "w")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message == "!test":
        await message.channel.send("you failed the test")

    await bot.process_commands(message)
            
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    
    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following guild: \n' 
        f'{guild.name} (id: {guild.id})'
    )
    
    count = 0
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
            if 'Bots' not in str(member.roles):
                 
                print(member.name, ' ')
                outP.write(member.name)
                outP.write("\n")
                count += 1
    print('Number of members: ' + str(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, regarding your questions, i am gonna answer them one by one :

1- client and bot are not diffrent at all, that means you shouldn't have any problem using the same functions on both(and neither are better than each other, meaning both will do the same stuff)

2- now to get your bot to receive/accept commands, you can use the `await` function, which basically waits for a command to be trigerred and will give out the output.

For example :

```py
@Client.command()
async def botping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"The bot's ping is {round(Client.latency*1000)} ms")
```

This command here (for example):

We are defining a command called "botping" and we are passing the `ctx` wich is the context the bot is writing, the you have the `await` wich will trigger the command when you type `"prefix"botping` in chat.

Hopefully this helped you a little bit about the concept of taking commands and that there is no diffrence between `client` and `bot`

For further information, i suggest that you check out the discord.py documentation:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: and feel free to ask any other question regarding this topic :)